# Symfony2 locale of user not retrieved

Tags: symfony, internationalization, request, locale

I want to get the user locale when he lands in my website and then stick it to the user (also stick the new one if he wants to change the language).

Yet I don't want the locale to appear in the url.

I implemented the LocaleListener from the Symfony2 doc but I am enable to get the user default locale at the first request.

This requests are giving me nothing for a response:

```
 $locale = $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_locale');
 $locale = $this->getRequest()->get('_locale');
```

While

```
$this->getRequest()
```

Sends effectively

```
GET /Twinkler1.2.3/web/app_dev.php/ HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 Cache-Control: max-age=0 Connection: keep-alive Cookie: __uvt=; PHPSESSID=f28e3958ecab05fe97d6fc6950eb72ec; SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2 Host: localhost:8888 Referer: http://localhost:8888/Twinkler1.2.3/web/app_dev.php/login User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36 X-Php-Ob-Level: 0
```

So how can I get the locale of the request (French here)?

Thanks in advance
Jules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$language = $request->getPreferredLanguage();
$request->setLocale($language);
```

Comment: thanks, this will indeed give me something, but always the default locale set in parameters.yml, not my real locale.